# Using Entity Framework with Archive databases

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, archive, data-warehouse

I am using Entity Framework 6 to do basic CRUD operations, which is all fine and good.  I need to be able to select my objects within a date range, which again, is pretty straightforward HOWEVER, these objects can be spread over several databases that are essentially warehouses for the previous year's data.  Once we're looking for them in a date range.

Example we want all the Foo objects between 1st of January 2015 and 9th of November 2016; the Foo data from 2015 would be in a different database.  This goes all the way back to 2005.  Not all the Schemas are identical.

We *could* have 11 EF projects, or 11 contexts and 11 connection strings.  This solution has the problem of having to add code every year when the archive is created.  This seems like a hack.  Swapping over to Azure storage methods isn't an option for the foreseeable future.

Any more graceful solutions?

Answer (score 2):

As long as all of your databases have the same (or similar) schemas for the entities you are wanting to query, you can have a single `DbContext` for all the databases and simply switch the connection string. You will have to manage the list of connection strings and loop through them, connecting to each and querying each one for the data. Of course if your databases are named in a consistent manner (e.g. according to year) you don't need to maintain all the connection strings. If your queries only ever hit a single DB, then you could calculate which is the appropriate connection string and use that. This will end up looking like standard sharding strategies. [Here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-scale-multishard-querying/) is a reference to Microsoft's SQL Azure sharding library for EF which may also be a solution

Alternatively, you may be able to use SQL Server's cross database querying abilities and set up a view across all the databases. This has maintenance issues, not to mention performance issues, but then I don't know the size of your data.

Comment: This sounds like a good plan!  So we'd be looking at some kind of regex to look at the connection string (presumably in the web.config?) and swap.  The schemas for the tables I'm looking for are similar but not identical.  Would I do remapping via fluent or perhaps just rely on EF's conventions to do the mapping for me?
(would +1, but I'm a <15 noob)

Comment: @Jimbob You can't remap EF at runtime, so either create multiple `DbContext`s or create your entities so that they encompass all the possible fields across all your DBs and then check for nulls on the fields which are inconsistent. You would do well to have an application layer in front of your data access layer to provide a consistent view of the data

Comment: So we'd be looking at a new context every year?  I'm thinking of having one of the DBAs sort this out server side with a stored proc that we can pass date parameters to.  Would that be better?

Comment: If the schemas keep changing, then you'll have to keep adding stored procs to the new DBs. I would personally go for views added to all the archive DBs which provide a consistent schema to query from. Having this in the DB is preferable to in the application code as it fixes the problem at the source

Comment: So what you're saying is it's the DBA's problem?  :-)  

There's a similar situation at the moment for similar functionality, I was just hoping EF would be able to handle it gracefully in code rather than calling to stored procs.